# Store on database vs Retrive data from network

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-syncadapter

I working on my app that uses "The movie database API".
This app just parse a json from the API and gets each movie information.
My question is what the better way to that.

First alternative is to build syncAdapter, check for updates each day for example, store all movies information on local database and update the UI from database.

Second alternative is just retrive the information from network on each request and update the UI.

Can anyone explain me wich way is better and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely the first alternative !!!!!

let's Suppose your app is used by thousand of users and you have chosen the second one .....oh poor server :)

I usualy create my own local database and syncronize it each "x" interval time depending on the type of information : if I have, for example, a list o category that I know they are rearly changed than I syncronize them each "2 days" ....For data that can be different more often I use 20 minutes and so on. This just avoid stressing server if the user goes in/out from your app.

Bye